[GSI_LOGGER]: The given client ID is not found
I am getting "GSI_LOGGER]: The given client ID is not found." as the error in my console. and also my key shows in the console with the way I log it in my main.jsx and hardcoded way. but not working  with import.meta.env.VITE_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
I log the key in the console and it works and use it hardcoded way which also works but using it with .env is not.


